# Iterating over grandchildren in XML Tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, svg

Here's something that doesn't work, and I'm trying to understand why. I seems very similar to the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` examples from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements), so I don't quite understand what is wrong.

Let's say we have the following XML file (a highly simplified example of an SVG Font file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<metadata>Text</metadata>
<defs>
<font id="ID">
    <glyph glyph-name="G1" unicode="..." 
d="path" />
    <glyph glyph-name="G2" unicode="..." 
d="path" />
    <glyph glyph-name="G3" unicode="..." 
d="path" />
    <glyph glyph-name="G4" unicode="..." 
d="path" />
  </font>
</defs></svg>
```

Now, why doesn't this return anything?

```py
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   ...:
   ...: tree = ET.parse('svg_font.xml')
   ...: root = tree.getroot()
   ...:
   ...: for glyph in root.findall('glyph'):
   ...:     print('Name: ' + glyph.attrib)
   ...:

In [2]:
```

Thanks for shedding some light for me on this!

Comment: According to the documentation, `element.findall()` finds only direct children of the given element.  In your document, the `<glyph>` tags are not direct children of the root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every tag should be name-spaced by '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}' because of this declaration [xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"] inside svg tag

for example instead of 'glyph' use '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}glyph'

every tag should be prefixed by '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}'

alse, instead of 'findall' use 'iter'!
change your "for" loop by the following

```
for glyph in El.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}glyph'):
    print('Name: ' + str(glyph.attrib))
```